# Intel AMT 0.0.0.0

Tags: networking, intel, system-administration

As part of testing on working laptops, I'm trying to organize a connection via *Intel AMT (Active Management Technology)*. All settings, according to the official manuals and guides of enthusiasts, have been completed. But according to information from `http://localhost:16992`, the IP address is
`0.0.0.0`.

Manual assignment of the address does not change the situation, it remains `0.0.0.0`. *DHCP* does not automatically assign an address either.

**Q1:** Could this be a consequence of some group policy of the corporate laptop, or is the problem something else?

**Q2:** Maybe it doesn't matter and I can still remotely connect to this laptop? (I can't check this  right now because all ports are being filtered)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that was easier than it seemed.

**First option:** on the `http://localhost:16992`, go to the *"Wireless Settings"* section and in the *"Wireless Management"* line select *"Enabled in S0"* or *"Enabled in S0, Sx / AC"*.

**Second option:** in MeshCommander go to *"Network Settings"* and in the section *"Wireless interface"* set the value of the line *"State"* similar to the first option.